# Generate QR codes in python

Tags: python, qr-code

I have an excel data frame with the variable- **participant_ID** in column A. I want to generate a QR code for over 70,000 participants using python and store the image in column B.

I need a simple python code that can generate these images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: CSV is text-only, so what do you mean with „store the image on EXCEL/CSV in column B.“?

Answer (score 2):

### `Use qrcode Module`

The code below will make the QR code of the given string and will save it as an image.

```
import qrcode
img = qrcode.make('https://stackoverflow.com/')
img.save('stackoverflow.png')
```

If the module is not installed, you can install it using the pip command:

```
pip install qrcode
```

### Note

The CSV file just stores text, you can save images, separately and store their names in column B. If you want to do it in excel, Excel does not store images within the given cell. It is not related to cells and can occupy multiple cells. So, **the best method is to store the images in the separate file (withing separate directory) and store their names within csv.**

Comment: Great. How can I generate 70,000 images and have them in Excel??

Comment: You can just generate images like data is `'a', 'b', 'c',...` you can generate images and save them to `/images/a.png`, `/images/b.png`, etc. and then you can put in excel file the address of the image. instead of putting the images.  Directly, storing images is not a good idea. (You can also use **base64 encoding** to store them in excel).